# How to recognize that TypeScript code is generated

Tags: typescript, code-generation, sourceanalyser

I maintain some analysers for C# code and TypeScript code. Those analysers shall skip generated code.

In C# it is rather simple because such class has attrribute System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode.

But how about TypeScript?
How can I generically recognize that the code is generated?

Comment: I think the only way you could do this is if the code generator puts some comments like `// @begin-generated-code` and `// @end-generated-code` to delimit the code that your analyser should ignore. Otherwise you could use heuristics like ignoring variables and functions whose names match some pattern.

Comment: In C# this attribute is widelly used by 3rd party tool where you have no control over such generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic way of doing this - generated typescript code can be indistinguishable from any other piece of typescript code.

The normal way of getting a tool to ignore generate TS code is to have to configuration that says which files/directories to ignore. This config is specific to each tool. For example eslint can use a .eslintignore file which might contain a lines like

```
dist
**/generated
```

Answer (score 0):

Name the generated file as something like "myClientAuto.ts", and have the static code analysis to skip files with suffix Auto, or some prefix if you want.
For generated C#, even the System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode is not really needed, if you put the generated codes in its own csproj project, and just opt out the project from CA.